# Building a Sencha based mobile app with a CakePHP backend

Tags: cakephp, mobile, extjs

I am using Cakephp 2 as a backend for a cafe shop mobile application. I would like to use Sencha as the mobile framework.

I have the following questions:

- Should I be building the frontend within the CakePHP framework as layouts/views or should I use CakePHP to create a RESTful webservice in order to access my data?

  - Can a complete cake application be wrapper using phonegap?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend building your mobile application separately from your Cake app. Like you mentioned, I would go with building a RESTful web service to provide your data. I would recommend using JSON, but that's your decision.

Cake provides built in support for building RESTful web services, but you probably knew this. :) http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/rest.html

A Cake application cannot be wrapped up inside PhoneGap since it needs to be run on a web server (Apache, IIS, etc)

Comment: Thanks, that has cleared up some misconceptions I had. I was aware of the RESTful web services Cake offers, just waiting for a chance to use them. Looks like this will be a suitable project. Thank you again.

Comment: Sounds like a great project to me. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a framework which does a lot of work for you, it's specifically to integrate CakePHP with Sencha Touch http://banchaproject.org